# Python: lookup failure in a .so file

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 installation that fails to launch git-cola. Here is the problem:

```
$ git-cola
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/git-cola", line 53, in <module>
    from cola.main import main
  File "/usr/share/git-cola/lib/cola/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import app
  File "/usr/share/git-cola/lib/cola/app.py", line 27, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWidgets
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qtpy/QtWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI13QOpenGLWidget, version Qt_5
```

The peculiar thing is that the cited library file `cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` seems to have the symbol already defined:

```
$ nm -gD /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep _ZTI13QOpenGLWidget
                 U _ZTI13QOpenGLWidget
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable led me astray. I undefined it and the problem vanished.